# How to use RecyclerView into another RecyclerView's adapter in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

In my application i have one list and into this this i have another list!(I know this is bad idea for UI but i should develop this!)
For show this lists i used `RecyclerView` and initialize other `RecyclerView` into previous `RecyclerView` **adapter**!

**Activity codes:**

```
class DashboardCardsActivity : BaseActivity(), DashboardCardsContracts.View {

    @NonNull
    private lateinit var presenter: DashboardCardsPresenterImpl
    private var context: Context = this
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var adapter: DashboardCardsAdapter
    private lateinit var layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager
    private val modelList: MutableList<UserPackageOrderResponse.Res.UserPackageOrder> = mutableListOf()
    private var isLoadingFlag = false
    private var isHasLoadedAll = false
    private var nextPage = 1
    //Token
    private var token = GoodPrefs.getInstance().getString(PrefsKey.USER_JWT_TOKEN.name, "")

    override var layoutId: Int = R.layout.activity_dashboard_cards

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //Initialize
        context = this
        presenter = DashboardCardsPresenterImpl(context, this)
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        adapter = DashboardCardsAdapter(context, modelList)
        //Init recyclerView
        recyclerView = dashboardCards_pullList.recyclerView
        recyclerView.initRecyclerView(layoutManager, adapter)
        //Set image to loader
        dashboardCards_pullList.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorAccent)
        //Init toolbar
        toolbarBase_toolbar.title = getString(R.string.basketCard)
        toolbarBase_toolbar.setToolbarBackWithFinish(this)
        //Call api
        getLazyPullLoader()
    }
```

**I write below codes :**

```
class DashboardListAdapter constructor(
    val context: Context, val model: MutableList<UserPackageOrderResponse.Res.UserPackageOrder>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DashboardCardsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var expansionlayout: ExpansionLayoutCollection = ExpansionLayoutCollection()
    private lateinit var registerTimeUtil: TimeUtils
    private var registerDateSplit: List<String> = emptyList()
    private var registerDate: List<String> = emptyList()
    private var orderState: String = ""
    private var layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager? = null
    private var adapter: DashboardCardsOrderAdapter
    private val orderModelList: MutableList<UserPackageOrderResponse.Res.UserPackageOrder.Order> = mutableListOf()

    init {
        expansionlayout.openOnlyOne(true)
        layoutManager = object : LinearLayoutManager(context) {
            override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean {
                return false
            }
        }
        adapter = DashboardCardsOrderAdapter(orderModelList)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_dashboard_card_list, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return model.size
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        expansionlayout.add(holder.getExpansions())
        //header
        holder.orderNumber.text = model[position].hashcode
        holder.rowNumber.text = "${position + 1}"
        //Set date
        registerDateSplit = model[position].createdAt.split(" ")
        registerDate = registerDateSplit[0].split("-")
        registerTimeUtil = TimeUtils(registerDate[0].toInt(), registerDate[1].toInt(), registerDate[2].toInt())
        holder.orderRegisterDate.text = registerTimeUtil.getIranianDate()
        //Order state
        orderState = model[position].status
        holder.setViewWithState(orderState, context)
        //Content prices
        holder.finalPrice.text = "${model[position].price.moneySeparating()} ${context.getString(R.string.toman)}"
        holder.paymentPrice.text = "${model[position].price.moneySeparating()} ${context.getString(R.string.toman)}"
        holder.postPrice.text = "${model[position].postFee.moneySeparating()} ${context.getString(R.string.toman)}"
        holder.discountPrice.text = "${model[position].discount.moneySeparating()} ${context.getString(R.string.toman)}"
        //init order list
        orderModelList.clear()
        orderModelList.addAll(model[position].orders)
        layoutManager?.let {
            holder.orderList.initRecyclerView(it, adapter)
        }
    }
}
```

But when running application show me **ForceClose** error and show me below message in **logCat** :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LayoutManager com.app.android.ui.home.fragments.dashboard.activities.carts_list.DashboardCardsAdapter$1@d33c634 is already attached to a RecyclerView: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{5a76c5d VFED..... ......ID 0,0-682,178 #7f080089 app:id/dashboardCard_orderList}, adapter:com.app.android.ui.home.fragments.dashboard.activities.carts_list.DashboardCardsOrderAdapter@83ba9d2, layout:com.app.android.ui.home.fragments.dashboard.activities.carts_list.DashboardCardsAdapter$1@d33c634, context:com.app.android.ui.home.fragments.dashboard.activities.carts_list.DashboardCardsActivity@79c2f05
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(RecyclerView.java:1340)
        at com.app.android.utils.ExtensionsKt.initRecyclerView(Extensions.kt:74)
        at com.app.android.ui.home.fragments.dashboard.activities.carts_list.DashboardCardsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DashboardCardsAdapter.kt:77)
        at com.app.android.ui.home.fragments.dashboard.activities.carts_list.DashboardCardsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DashboardCardsAdapter.kt:22)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
```

But after change my code with below case not show me any error, but **scrolling is very slowly and show lag**!

```
//init order list
orderModelList.clear()
orderModelList.addAll(model[position].orders)
layoutManager = object : LinearLayoutManager(context) {
    override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean {
        return false
    }
}
layoutManager?.let {
    holder.orderList.initRecyclerView(it, adapter)
}
```

I initialized `layoutManager` in `onBindView()`, then not show me error but show me many lag when scrolling on items!

How can i fix this?

Comment: You are attaching the wrong layoutmanager to another recyclerview. Use another layoutmanager

Comment: @sanjeev, i used GridLayoutManager , but again show me error!

Comment: where is layoutManager used? it seems can be removed completely, Adapter should not keep a layout manager.

Comment: @AIMINPAN, for adapter one, i initialize layout manager into fragment. and for fragment two i initialize layout manager into adapter one! can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined this:

```
private var layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager? = null
```

Define another one say,

```
private var layoutManager1: LinearLayoutManager? = null
```

Assign that to your second `RecyclerView` and run it. It should work.

P.S: Not familiar with `Kotlin`, in Java we use

`recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MyActivity.this));`

Comment: when use your above code again show me ForceClose error! but this code : `recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MyActivity.this));` such as `layoutManager = object : LinearLayoutManager(context) {
    override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean {
        return false
    }
}` ! this way slowly scroll items!

Comment: use `layoutManager` for one and `layoutManager1` for another!

Comment: `DashboardCardsOrderAdapter` is using the same `layoutManager`

Comment: yes my friend i know this. but layoutManager write into fragment and layoutManager1 write into adapter!

Comment: Please see my update post. into `activity` i have `DashboardCardsAdapter` and for this i set layout manager. and i used `DashboardListAdapter` into `DashboardCardsAdapter` and for new adapter i set layout manager into `DashboardCardsAdapter` !

Comment: What is `it` in `holder.orderList.initRecyclerView(it, adapter)`?

Comment: In fact, it's the layer manager! i used it for nullPointerException! do you know how can i fix it?

Comment: This might be of some help to you! https://android.jlelse.eu/easily-adding-nested-recycler-view-in-android-a7e9f7f04047

Comment: are you here my friend?